# IOS8 UiTableViewController grouped tableView like iOS6 style wrong left right margin

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, grouped-table

i found this guide for make grouped table view with iOS6 style:
[ios7 grouped rounded tableview](http://benoitlayer.com/development/2014/03/02/iOS7-grouped-rounded-table-view) but if i apply this code in UITableViewController i have a wrong lateral margins to view for my cells.

i need use UiTableViewController instead of UiViewController with TableView for using refresh table, for automatic scroll cell with textfield when keyboard appears and more...

any idea?

this is my result:
[image]

but I would like to get this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not embed your UITableViewController into another UIViewController, as a child view controller?
You will be able to easily change the margins of your container view.

[image]

Comment: sorry , maybe I did not explain well, my problem regarding the margins of the cell relative to the container view, not the separator line..

Comment: OK sorry, I changed my answer so.

Comment: it's very complicated navigation's hierarchy. if for example i have a Navigation Controller for Home, when i open modally other Navigation Controller with container and Tableviewcontroller embedded if i select a row how i can dismiss modal view controller?

Comment: Maybe it's a bit complicated but you don't have much choise if you really want to use a UITableViewController. This class doesn't allow to make a lot of things on the view.

To dismiss the modal view controller, it is easy if you use segues (recommanded by Apple) instead of calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` method.
You can easily unwind your current view controller to your home view controller by just performing a single segue.
Search for "unwind segue" for more info.